# Will the "Pixel Knight TR-332" radio flash trigger work with a Canon 350D?

Tags: canon, flash, wireless-triggers, ttl, canon-350d

I am using a Canon 350D/XT and found some information on web that the `Pixel Knight TR-332` radio flash may be incompatible with that particular Canon camera due to DIGIC II and lack of Flash functions in camera menu.

I am wondering what, exactly, "incompatibility" means:

- Not working at all
- Missing some functions but generally shoots in (e)TTL / M etc

---

Edit:
[Source of information](http://www.flickr.com/groups/strobist/discuss/72157623797323770/)

Topic owner answered me that is should work, but I would prefer to know from someone really using it.

Comment: you might get more response if you posted a link to the information that you found.  I don't know if Pixel Knight is a well known thing, but linking to a sit about it might also help.

Comment: Where did you get this information? From what I remember it should work. Can't find the official docs for some reason, but this site seems to indicate the same: http://www.gadgetinfinity.com/product.php?productid=17460&cat=317&page=1 No guarantees though. Perhaps you can try contacting them directly [through their website](http://www.pixelhk.com/pixelhk.com/Contact.aspx)?

Comment: @AJ Finch, added source. @BKevelham, thanks I think I will try - hoped that community answer comes faster :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDF review mentioned on the same site (http://www.alphapics.co.nz/Pages/Pixel%20Knight%20TR-332.pdf) lists the 350 on the Compatible list.  Sorry I can't answer your question more directly (I'd add this as a comment instead of an answer if I had enough reputation yet)